# Using subquery inside ST_Distance

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

How can I run this query in postgresql and make it work?

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
SELECT coordinates FROM points WHERE id = 1,
ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.809442 54.096305)', 4326),26986));
```

If I run it by replacing the second select for coordinates it works, but I don't see how I can make a select work inside there (I have mainly used subqueries with `in` and such).

Thanks to @fradal83's answer, I don't have syntax errors, but now I get this:

```
ERROR. Operation on two GEOMETRIES with different SRIDs
```

I tried to do what it says [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32709/query-failed-error-operation-on-two-geometries-with-different-srid), but it didn't do anything, I still get the same error (and the updates did succeed).

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
SELECT ST_Distance( (SELECT coordinates FROM points WHERE id = 1),
                     ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.809442 54.096305)', 4326), 26986)
                  );
```

Comment: I get `ERROR:  Operation on two GEOMETRIES with different SRIDs`. When I created the table, I used `SELECT AddGeometryColumn('points','coordinates','4326','POINT',2);`. Why won't it work? Isn't "4326" the SRID"?

Comment: The srid of points.coordinates must be the same as the second parameter (26986) or vice versa

Comment: Ooooohhhhhh...! Got it now. I had to switch `4326),26986` for `26986),4326`

Comment: I finally got it working, but this query: `SELECT ST_Distance( (SELECT coordinates FROM houses WHERE id = 1), (SELECT coordinates FROM points WHERE id = 2)) as Distance;` returns `0.00159668562966777`, where it should be `175.40` or something. What is causing this?

Comment: Using 4326, you are getting a distance in deegrees, while you probably need meters. Convert to another srid or use https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html or https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html

Comment: Which one should I use for meters? I used this page, and it says it gives meters: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html